# Using the live refresh links breaks the permalink button

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, permalink

I noticed on SO earlier that clicking on any of the various live refresh links causes the permalink button on the bottom left of a post to misbehave. I specifically noticed it with:

- The `this post has been edited` link
- The `this post has new answers` link

After using either of those to reload a post, clicking the `link` button on the post will cause the little permalink popup to fade in like normal, but then immediately fade out, meaning that it's not possible to actually copy the URL.

I saw this on Firefox 12 (Win7) and Chrome 19 (OSX). Performing a manual refresh of the page fixes it. It was reproducible with all of my userscripts disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click handlers on the "link" links were unnecessarily bound again when refreshing a post after an edit, so each click effectively counted as *two* clicks. And since it's supposed to toggle (i.e. clicking again hides the popup), the "second click" caused the popup to immediately disappear again.

Fixed in the next build.