# Link button pop-up does not stay and allow me to select copy

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the live refresh links breaks the permalink button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133428/using-the-live-refresh-links-breaks-the-permalink-button)

The link button on a question (stackoverflow.com) does not stay open when I click on it.  It insta-closes.

I would post a picture but it does not say open to let me take a screenshot.

Now it seems to work.  Is it possible this problem only manifests when it needs to be refreshed?  I'm not sure why I had the problem, but that could be it.

Comment: This happened to me last week as well. So repro here.

Comment: Which browser with version you are using?

Comment: Reproduced. There must be some double event binding happening when getting data updates via realtime.

Comment: @TimStone - That is a little different because they can see the link text, for me the window went away.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - I'm using Chrome v 20.0.1132.47 m

Comment: Is it possible this could happen when not all of the JS files have loaded? I have seen some other intermittent behavior that seems to fix itself with a refresh, and it seems to coincide with cases where the loading bar is still spinning or there is still some "waiting for..." in the status bar.

Comment: Sounds similar to what I saw here: [Using the live refresh links breaks the permalink button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133428)

Comment: @eldarerathis - That could be the same thing, I'm now sure if I clicked those links or not.